# What happens inside this python code?

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I am taking the 'Intro to Computer Science' course on Udacity and i was asked to solve this problem in a quiz:

Define a procedure, add_to_index,
that takes 3 inputs:

- an index: [[,[,...]],...]
- a keyword: String
- a url: String

If the keyword is already
in the index, add the url
to the list of urls associated
with that keyword.

If the keyword is not in the index,
add an entry to the index: [keyword,[url]]

The aim of this quiz is to have a list named index which consists of lists which have keywords and their associated urls
The index list will look like this:
[[keyword1,[url1,url2,url3]],[keyword2,[url1,url2]],.....]

I am supposed to write the function. This was my answer which was accepted by the judge.

```
index = []
def add_to_index(index,keyword,url):
    p=[]
    q=[]
    if index==[]:
        q.append(url)
        p.append(keyword)
        p.append(q)
        index.append(p)
    else:
        for e in index:
            if e[0]==keyword:
                e[1].append(url)
                return index
        index.append([keyword,[url]])
    return index
```

This answer was deemed successful by the judge.
Now the strange part begins(for me :p). This was the code which was given in the course

```
index=[]
def add_to_index(index,keyword,url):
    for e in index:
        if e[0]==keyword:
            e[1].append(url)
            return
    index.append([keyword,[url]])

add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://udacity.com') #Test Case
add_to_index(index,'computing','http://acm.org')   #Test Case
add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://npr.org')     #Test Case
print index
```

As you can see, the core of this code is similar to my code. They both give the same output. This is the output given by both the codes.

```
[['udacity', ['htxtp://udacity.com', 'htxtp://npr.org']], ['computing', ['htxtp://acm.org']]]
```

(I added x in the middle of http words because I don't have enough reputation to include links. The output doesn't actually contain the x alphabets in the middle of http words)

So these are my questions:

1. In the code given by the course, there is nothing after the return keyword.    So how does the function know what to return? Also, if the keyword doesn't already exist in the index list, the for loop will be exited without the code in if conditional being executed. Thus the program will never execute the return statement. Then how does the function return the index list?
2. In the code given by the course, there is no arrangement for an empty index list passed as parameter while in my code, there is. The code to handle the empty index list in my code is used only once(when the function is called for the very first time) but nevertheless, it's important(or that's what I thought). Then how can the code provided by the course get away without including this arrangement? Why does it not break down when the function is called for the very first time? How can it access e[0] and e[1] elements of a list of empty index list?

Thank you for answering this super long question :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It doesn't return anything. It modifies the list `index` which has been passed in.
2. The course code never indexes elements 0 and 1 of an empty list. It is iterating over the list `index`, and each item in `index` is itself a list (sublist). This is guaranteed to have at least two elements since when each sublist is added, it is added with two elements (and the second element is a list itself: a sub-sublist). If `index` itself is empty, the `for` loop does nothing: it is executed once for each element, and if there are 0 elements, then it is executed 0 times.

Comment: Ah, I see. I must keep in mind that lists are mutable. Thank you for answering. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Lists are mutable. The list of urls is modified in-place.  No need to return it.
2. The code goes through each element of the index. If there's none of them the`for` loop does not run and the keyword is appended to the index.
   Vice versa, as you can see, when the keyword is found the code appends the url and returns.

**Note:** in my opinion the code is flawed, since it can add duplicate urls to the same keyword.

An alternative, more pythonic, way of doing it is

```
def add_to_index(index,keyword,url):
    kg = (el[1] for el in index if el[0] == keyword)
    try:
        ul = next(kg)
    except StopIteration:
        index.append([keyword,[url]])
    else:
        if url not in ul:
            ul.append(url)
```

So calling it with

```
index = []
add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://udacity.com') #Test Case
add_to_index(index,'computing','http://acm.org')   #Test Case
add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://npr.org')     #Test Case
add_to_index(index,'udacity','http://udacity.com') # 1st test case again
print index
```

produces

```
[['udacity', ['http://udacity.com', 'http://npr.org']], ['computing', ['http://acm.org']]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer and the answer above your's helped a lot. And special thanks for showing me how to address the duplicate urls issue. :)